# ReferencesAny nhibernate mapping in entity framework?

Tags: mapping

I'm wondering how to create mapping in entity framework,
that is similar to ReferenceAny in fluent nhibernate.

What I got:

Entities:

```
public abstract class Document : Entity
{
   public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentA : Document 
{
}

public class DocumentB : Document
{
}

public class Feature : Entity
{
    public IEntity Super { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In Feature mapping:

```
ReferencesAny(x => x.Super)
    .EntityTypeColumn("type")
    .EntityIdentifierColumn("super")
    .AddMetaValue<DocumentA>("DoucmentA")
    .AddMetaValue<DokumentB>("DocumentB")
    .IdentityType<int>();
```

In DocumentA mapping:

```
HasMany<Feature>(x => x.Features)
   .AsSet()
   .Inverse()
   .KeyColumn("super").Not.KeyNullable()
   .Where("type = 'DocumentA'")
   .Fetch.Join()
   .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

In DocumentB mapping:

```
HasMany<Feature>(x => x.Features)
   .AsSet()
   .Inverse()
   .KeyColumn("super").Not.KeyNullable()
   .Where("type = 'DocumentB'")
   .Fetch.Join()
   .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

This kind of mapping gives me clean Features table with columns: id, value, type, super,
where type act as discriminator and super is document id.

How map this in EF to achieve Features table with same columns, since I can't change it?

Comment: looks like not supported and won't be in the near future https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7623